# Slow query with good plan

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

We have two server, the newest is going to replace the oldest one. They almost the same regarding performances, except for a single query.The same query in two different servers (same database definition, same data, indexes just rebuilt from scratch) take MUCH more time in the newest instance.

The two plans are identical and the qwery pretty simple:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..17.83 rows=1 width=2262) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3
   ->  Index Scan using psan_para_fk_ix on parasetana a0  (cost=0.00..9.48 rows=1 width=1735) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (((ca)::text = 'r'::text) AND (idp = 36678502::numeric))
         Filter: (flg = '1'::bpchar)
         Buffers: shared hit=3
   ->  Index Scan using seta_pk on seta a1  (cost=0.00..8.33 rows=1 width=527) (never executed)
         Index Cond: (((a1.ca)::text = 'r'::text) AND (a1.idgrla = a0.idgrla ) AND (a1.prog = a0.prog_set))
         Filter: (a1.flgp = '0'::bpchar)
 Total runtime: 0.153 ms
(10 rows)
```

Time: 2217.074 ms

As you can see, the total runtime is 0.2ms. It is so in both the new and the old server. However the Time in the old server is 30ms, in the new server is 200 times more (2.2 seconds vs 30 millis)

What can cause such difference? The postgresql doc says that in select statements the total runtime and the the time should be nearly the same...

thanks

Comment: Have you analyzed or vacuumed the tables in question?

Comment: yes, both. The table btw was created from a dump of the one in the other server, so it should have  been optimal from the start.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is a simple join using nested loops with appropriate indexing. The problem should be due to bad caching of second (large) table. Here possibly the second table is badly clustered with respect to the index used. Try `CLUSTER` command to see if it helps.

Also you may try to change plan. The options you may need - swap join order, use hash join.

Comment: Isn't cache time accounted in  Total runtime (0.153 ms)? The documentation states total runtime "does not include parsing, rewriting, or planning time" [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/using-explain.html]
Also, what could alter caching strategy between the two servers?